# Return ID based on maximum date for each organisation SQL Sever 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return a single ID for each organisation based on the maximum date and am a bit lost.

I have created a dummy dataset below to replicate mine.

| ID | OrganisationID | record date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 21/01/2022 |
| 2 | 100 | 28/01/2022 |
| 3 | 200 | 17/01/2021 |
| 4 | 120 | 14/08/2019 |
| 5 | 100 | 21/05/2019 |
| 6 | 150 | 12/04/2021 |
| 7 | 100 | 07/02/2022 |
| 8 | 200 | 21/03/2022 |
| 9 | 150 | 16/09/2021 |
| 10 | 100 | 01/02/2022 |

I would like to return the ID of the entry with the highest date for each Organisation, results would looke like

| ID | OrgsansiationID | recordDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 200 | 21/03/2022 |
| 7 | 100 | 07/02/2022 |
| 9 | 150 | 16/09/2021 |
| 4 | 120 | 14/08/2019 |

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done with a `top 1 with ties`

```
select top 1 with ties
       o.id,
       o.organisationid,
       o.record_date
from   organisation o
order by row_number() over (partition by o.organisationid order by o.record_date desc)
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b439a1d5c8b580b2c26cdee23c579cdb)

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it's because this method is already in the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412942/2029983), @GuidoG . That or this question is asked almost as often as "How do I split a delimited string into rows" and they feel that we don't need *another* answer telling using the same thing. Just throwing ideas out there.